# How to pop up custom Keyboard on focus on EditText in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I have designed a custom Keyboard in Android following [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) tutorial. 
Now by default, when one clicks or focuses on an `EditText` in Android, it pops up the default keyboard. But I want my custom keyboard to pop up when focused instead of the default keyboard. Is there any way I can achieve it in Android?

Thank you for your time!